# Jquery "for" loop to find how many children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to alert how many children are in a div with the class ".child". Ex: There are five ".child" inside of a div. I am not sure why my for loop to do this doesn't work, and I realize there are better ways but I am practicing for loops. Thanks. The problem can be found here http://jqexercise.droppages.com/#page_0013_

```
for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++){
    if($(".child:nth-child(i)") == true){    
    }
    else {
      alert(i);
      break;      
    }
}
```

Comment: Because of the `javscript` tag: `document.querySelectorAll(".child").length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get number of `.child` in a div like following.

```js
var num = $('div').find('.child').length;
console.log(num);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span class="child">Child</span>
    <span class="child">Child</span>
    <span class="child">Child</span>
    <span class="child">Child</span>
    <span class="child">Child</span>
    <span class="child">Child</span>
</div>
```

**Update:** If you want to use for loop then you can do it like below using `jquery` `eq()` function.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if ($('.child').eq(i).length) {

    }
    else {
        alert(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

You used `i` as string. Using `nth-child()` do it like below.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    if ($(".child:nth-child(" + i + ")").length) {

    }
    else {
        alert(i-1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: For sure, I was just experimenting with "for" loops even though it doesn't make sense to.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
alert($('div .child').length);
```

Comment: For sure, I was just experimenting with "for" loops even though it doesn't make sense to.

Answer (score 1):

```
var intChildrenCount = $("div .child").length;
```

Comment: For sure, I was just experimenting with "for" loops even though it doesn't make sense to.

Answer (score 1):

`i` inside if condition is a string, not a variable, do this :

```
if ( $( ".child:nth-child(" + i + ")" ) == true )
```

Comment: you are a genius. Although it only alerts "1" even if the answer should be 5.

Comment: See @azim's answer mate

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrChildren = $("div .child");
$.each(arrChildren,function(){
   // Here you will get child's HTML one by one
   console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: I apologize I didn't realize it was console.log. Thank you!